# Mule 3.4 -JUnit TestCase failing over DataMapper MessageProcessor in Mule ESB

Tags: junit, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

kindly help me to overcome this issue. I have developed my mule flow ( version 3.4). When i run the JUnit Test case, Flow running fine till the `Data Mapper` message processor. Once after reaching dataMapper flow throwing the error like `.grf doesnot exits`. But when i run the same flow in Mule server able to get the response successfully.Problem happens only when running the JUnit TestCase.
Observation: When we hit through JUit TestCase , DataMapper location is not being recognized in the classpath. Please find my complete error

---

ERROR [Thread-0] [org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy] - 
Message               : com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException: The data mapping graph C:\Documents and Settings\UserID\Desktop\Mule-Project\MuleProject\Transformation_InputRequest.grf does not exists (java.lang.RuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Code : MULE ERROR -2 
Exception stack is:
1. The data mapping graph C:\Documents and Settings\UserID\Desktop\Mule-Project\MuleProject\Transformation_InputRequest.grf does not exists (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperCreationException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.graphfactory.AppHomeCloverGraphFactoryImpl:52 (null)

---

I have observed -there is the JIRA raised for this issue:`https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-3400` but it seems to be open state. 
I'm not able to proceed other success and failure scenario's Junit TestCase since i have dataMapper in main flow itself.
Is there any way to overcome this issue to proceed further. Kindly suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following to your test class:

```
@Override
protected Properties getStartUpProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties(super.getStartUpProperties());
    properties.put(MuleProperties.APP_HOME_DIRECTORY_PROPERTY, new File("mappings").getAbsolutePath());
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Seba. It works fine. I have done some modification in the above code. I have added file read logic in between the code snippet in order to get out from Data Mapper error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is like 2 years old. I had this same problem and the above solution does work. However one can avoid that extra code. I found the problem to be a space in my directory path. Try moving your project from 
`C:\Documents and Settings\UserID\Desktop\Mule-Project\MuleProject\Transformation_InputRequest.grf`
to `C:\Projects` or any other directory with no spaces in the path name.